# What is the use of length in SQL

Tags: sql

I am a self-learner and beginner learning SQL. I need to ensure the dataset is consistent. The statement used below:

```
SELECT
      DISTINCT drive_wheels
FROM
      cars.car_info
```

To check if this is the case, use a `LENGTH` query statement.

```
SELECT     
 DISTINCT drive_wheels
 LENGTH(drive_wheels) AS string_length
FROM
 cars.car_info;
```

**the LENGTH statement doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Please add some sample data.

Comment: Your SQL is missing a comma after DISTINCT drive_wheels.  Why should the LENGTH ensure data consistency? Should the drive_wheels contain data of the same length? In which case you would be better off checking for data where it was not true EG `SELECT * FROM cars.car_info WHERE LENGTH (drive_wheels) <> 10` (assuming 10 to be the required size). Better still would be a `CONSTRAINT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using MySQL or a MySQL-compatible database engine. In other database engines the implementation of the `LENGTH` could be different.

`LENGTH` is an SQL function that returns the number of bytes in a string.

In your SQL query, it returns the length of the content of the `drive_wheels` field as a string measured in bytes. If your field contains a numeric value then it's not the correct function to use - you can simply return the field as is.

Ref: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-string-length/

Note: number of bytes in a string and number of characters in a string can be different when for example UTF-8 encoding is used and the string contains characters outside of the normal Latin characters. Those characters might require 2, 3 or 4 bytes to represent.

Comment: How do you know the OP is using MySql?

Comment: @GSerg wait, MySQL isn't the only database? :)

Comment: @GSerg Good point. It's the most common but far from the only one. I edited my answer to specify that I assume we are talking about MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

The length function returns the number of characters in a string, so in layman's terms, how many letters are in the word.

Examples

```
Length('hello') = 5
Length('foo') = 3
Length('goodbye') = 7
```

Not sure what is in the drive wheels column though

Comment: That example is very helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The string `LENGTH` functions returns the length of the string in bytes. `DISTINCT drive_wheels LENGTH(drive_wheels) AS string_length FROM cars.car_info` The above query will return the length of drive_wheels from the car_info table.